# Live Wallpaper issue

Tags: live-wallpaper

I am developing a Live Wallpaper Application. In it when I try to set a live wallpaper for the first time it is done, but while doing it again it is not overwritten. If I put an image in between it is done. Then will anyone help me to know how to overwrite one live wallpaper on other?

my code is here:

```
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = 
    WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                        try {
                            wallpaperManager.setResource(pos);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mResourceId = R.raw.screen_1;
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
                        intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                                new ComponentName(SetwallpaperActivity.this, LiveWallpaperService.class));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }).start();
```

Service Class:

```
public class LiveWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {
    private AnimationEngine mEngine;
    private int mDeviceWidth;
    private int mDeviceHeight;

    public static final Handler mDrawHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mDeviceWidth = AppUtils.getDeviceWidth(LiveWallpaperService.this);
        mDeviceHeight = AppUtils.getDeviceHeight(LiveWallpaperService.this);
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        try {
            mEngine = new AnimationEngine();
            return mEngine;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            stopSelf();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void doProcessing() throws IOException {
        if (mEngine != null) {
            mEngine.process(mResourceId);
        }

    }

    /**
     * The class is used to start live wallpaper engine.
     *
     * @author vishalbodkhe
     */
    class AnimationEngine extends Engine {
        private Movie mMovie;
        private int mMovieDuration;
        public Runnable mAnimationRunnable;
        float mScaleX;
        float mScaleY;
        int mWhen;
        long mStart;

        AnimationEngine() throws IOException {
            process(mResourceId);
            mWhen = -1;
          /*  mAnimationRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    drawAnimation();
                }
            };*/
        }

        public void process(int resId) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
                    mMovieDuration = mMovie.duration();
                    mScaleX = mDeviceWidth / (1f * mMovie.width());
                    mScaleY = mDeviceHeight / (1f * mMovie.height());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } finally {
                    is.close();
                }
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Unable to open input gif file");
            }

            mWhen = -1;
            mAnimationRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    drawAnimation();
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mDrawHandler.removeCallbacks(mAnimationRunnable);
            mAnimationRunnable = null;
        }



        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
            if (visible) {


                drawAnimation();
            } else {
                mDrawHandler.removeCallbacks(mAnimationRunnable);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                     int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
            mDeviceHeight = height;
            mDeviceWidth = width;
            mScaleX = width / (1f * mMovie.width());
            mScaleY = height / (1f * mMovie.height());
            drawAnimation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                                     float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset,
                                     int yPixelOffset) {
            super.onOffsetsChanged(xOffset, yOffset, xOffsetStep, yOffsetStep,
                    xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset);
            drawAnimation();
        }

        /**
         * Method to draw animation
         */
        private void drawAnimation() {
            findDuration();
            SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas canvas = null;

            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
              /*  synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    drawPicture(canvas);
                }*/

                if (canvas != null) {

                    drawPicture(canvas);
                }


            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {

                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

            mDrawHandler.removeCallbacks(mAnimationRunnable);
            if (isVisible()) {
                mDrawHandler.postDelayed(mAnimationRunnable, 1000L / 25L);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Method to get duration
         */
        private void findDuration() {
            if (mWhen == -1L) {
                mWhen = 0;
                mStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            } else {
                long mDiff = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStart;
                if (mMovieDuration > 0) {
                    mWhen = (int) (mDiff % mMovieDuration);
                } else {
                    mMovieDuration = mMovie.duration();
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * Method to draw images on canvas
         */
        private void drawPicture(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(mScaleX, mScaleY);
            mMovie.setTime(mWhen);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }


}
```